# ArcLayout pixelize

Tags: android, layout, automatic-ref-counting

I use https://github.com/florent37/ArcLayout for arc to layout

But my layout pixelize

```
<com.github.florent37.arclayout.ArcLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                app:arc_height="20dp"
                app:arc_cropDirection="cropOutside"
                app:arc_position="bottom">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="#fff">
                </LinearLayout>
            </com.github.florent37.arclayout.ArcLayout>
```

I found this topic : https://github.com/florent37/ArcLayout/issues/8

But i dont understand how use below code:

```
@override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
int saveCount = canvas.saveLayer(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null, Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);
super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY));
canvas.drawPath(clipPath, paint);
canvas.restoreToCount(saveCount);
paint.setXfermode(null);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to this file in your project  : https://github.com/florent37/ArcLayout/blob/master/arclayout/src/main/java/com/github/florent37/arclayout/ArcLayout.java

Update `dispatchDraw` method with your code suggested in issue.

**EDIT**

Replace your ArcLayout.java with this file:

```
public class ArcLayout extends FrameLayout {

    private ArcLayoutSettings settings;

    private int height = 0;

    private int width = 0;

    private Path clipPath;

    public ArcLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null);
    }

    public ArcLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    public void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        settings = new ArcLayoutSettings(context, attrs);
        settings.setElevation(ViewCompat.getElevation(this));

        /**
         * If hardware acceleration is on (default from API 14), clipPath worked correctly
         * from API 18.
         *
         * So we will disable hardware Acceleration if API < 18
         *
         * https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#unsupported
         * Section #Unsupported Drawing Operations
         */
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
            setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }
    }

    private Path createClipPath() {
        final Path path = new Path();

        float arcHeight = settings.getArcHeight();

        switch (settings.getPosition()){
            case ArcLayoutSettings.POSITION_BOTTOM:{
                if (settings.isCropInside()) {
                    path.moveTo(0, 0);
                    path.lineTo(0, height);
                    path.quadTo(width / 2, height - 2 * arcHeight, width, height);
                    path.lineTo(width, 0);
                    path.close();
                } else {
                    path.moveTo(0, 0);
                    path.lineTo(0, height - arcHeight);
                    path.quadTo(width / 2, height + arcHeight, width, height - arcHeight);
                    path.lineTo(width, 0);
                    path.close();
                }
                break;
            }
            case ArcLayoutSettings.POSITION_TOP:
                if (settings.isCropInside()) {
                    path.moveTo(0, height);
                    path.lineTo(0, 0);
                    path.quadTo(width / 2, 2 * arcHeight, width, 0);
                    path.lineTo(width, height);
                    path.close();
                } else {
                    path.moveTo(0, arcHeight);
                    path.quadTo(width / 2, -arcHeight, width, arcHeight);
                    path.lineTo(width, height);
                    path.lineTo(0, height);
                    path.close();
                }
                break;
            case ArcLayoutSettings.POSITION_LEFT:
                if (settings.isCropInside()) {
                    path.moveTo(width, 0);
                    path.lineTo(0, 0);
                    path.quadTo(arcHeight * 2, height / 2, 0, height);
                    path.lineTo(width, height);
                    path.close();
                } else {
                    path.moveTo(width, 0);
                    path.lineTo(arcHeight, 0);
                    path.quadTo(-arcHeight, height / 2, arcHeight, height);
                    path.lineTo(width, height);
                    path.close();
                }
                break;
            case ArcLayoutSettings.POSITION_RIGHT:
                if (settings.isCropInside()) {
                    path.moveTo(0, 0);
                    path.lineTo(width, 0);
                    path.quadTo(width - arcHeight * 2, height / 2, width, height);
                    path.lineTo(0, height);
                    path.close();
                } else {
                    path.moveTo(0, 0);
                    path.lineTo(width - arcHeight, 0);
                    path.quadTo(width + arcHeight, height / 2, width - arcHeight, height);
                    path.lineTo(0, height);
                    path.close();
                }
                break;
        }

        return path;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        if (changed) {
            calculateLayout();
        }
    }

    private void calculateLayout() {
        if (settings == null) {
            return;
        }
        height = getMeasuredHeight();
        width = getMeasuredWidth();
        if (width > 0 && height > 0) {

            clipPath = createClipPath();
            ViewCompat.setElevation(this, settings.getElevation());
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP && !settings.isCropInside()) {
                ViewCompat.setElevation(this, settings.getElevation());
                setOutlineProvider(new ViewOutlineProvider() {
                    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                    @Override
                    public void getOutline(View view, Outline outline) {
                        outline.setConvexPath(clipPath);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }




       @Override
        protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Paint paint= new Paint();   
       paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        int saveCount = canvas.saveLayer(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null, Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY));
        canvas.drawPath(clipPath, paint);
        canvas.restoreToCount(saveCount);
        paint.setXfermode(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: How use it ? i dont understand. please help me more

Comment: Thank you. but i get error cannot resolved symbol 'paint'. is add private Paint paint; in class ?

Comment: initialize paint there.

Comment: sorry. i need more help. first i create ArcLayout.java, now What should we do?

Comment: Thank you. i have 2 problems yet. 1- this line error new ArcLayoutSettings(context, attrs); => Error:(42, 20) error: ArcLayoutSettings(Context,AttributeSet) is not public in ArcLayoutSettings; cannot be accessed from outside package. 2- How use ArcLayout in project ?

Comment: Make ArcLayoutSettings file public

Comment: Thx, i fixed by <app.zzz.com.ArcLayout in xml

Comment: Can you please update this to latest code present at his github repository and not gradle library